# Find distinct groups within table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server which has records like:

```
ID              Name
---------------------
1           CTSH
1           JPMC
1           CSFB
2           CSFB
2           JPMC
2           CTSH
3           CTSH
3           MSSB
4           CTSH
4           JPMC
4           CSFB
5           CTSH
5           MSSB
```

I want to find out all the distinct groups based on Name. For example, all the Names with ID 1 are exactly same as the Name with ID 2 and 4. In this case, I would like to select all the records for ID 1 only.

Here is how my final output should look like:

```
ID              Name
---------------------
1           CTSH
1           JPMC
1           CSFB
3           MSSB
3           CTSH
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to aggregate the `ID` for every name using `MIN()`

```
SELECT  MIN(ID) ID, Name
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73c57/1)

Comment: I have edited the final output which I missed intially. Also, this ID may not be numeric. Challenge here is to find out distinct group.

Answer (score 0):

By simply doing this all the distinct names would be displayed along with their min ID allocated to it:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT Name , MIN(ID) ID
FROM    tableName
Group BY NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated, because you are trying to match two sets.  Here is one way to approach this, using `full outer join`:

```
select *
from t
where t.id in (
    select distinct min(a.id) as idunique
    from (select t1.id, t2.id
          from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as NumNames
                from t
               ) t1 full outer join
               (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as NumNames
                from t
               ) t2
               on t1.name = t2.name
          group by t1.id, t2.id
          having count(*) = t1.NumNames and count(*) = t2.NumNames
        ) a
    group by t2.id
  )
```

Ok, this is rather complicated.  Two ids have the asme set of names when all the names match and the number of matching names is the number of names on each one.  This is what the aggregation/full-outer-join subquery does.  The result is a set of all pairs of ids that match (including the identity).

Then, the minimum id is extracted from these pairs, using aggregation with `min()`, and this id is the one chosen for the final join to get all the rows corresponding to that set.

Comment: Hi Gordan - I tried to run this query but didn't work. Any idea with updated resultset? IS there any way to use self-join to get the intended result?